# PhpStorm - PHP 5.6 - Xdebug 2.5.5 Docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I've be searching a days to a solution but not success. I installed Xdebug 2.5.5 in my Docker container and added it to my php.ini as follow

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
```

When I run `php -v` I got

```
PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2019 00:10:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

But the I try to add on PhpStorm the CLI interpreter I got "Debugger: Not Installed

```
PHP version: 5.6.40
PHP CLI: /usr/local/bin/php PHP CGI: Not Installed (php-cgi sapi is necessary to use built-in web server) 
Loaded Configuration File: Not Found
Additional .ini files parsed:  /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-calendar.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gettext.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-shmop.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sockets.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sysvmsg.ini
Debugger extension: Not Found
Loaded extensions:  calendar, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, ereg, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gettext, hash, iconv, json, libxml, mbstring, mhash, mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd, openssl, pcre, PDO, pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, Phar, posix, readline, Reflection, session, shmop, SimpleXML, sockets, SPL, sqlite3, standard, sysvmsg, tokenizer, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, Zend OPcache, zlib
```

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.6 is years beyond end-of-life, has known security issues and won't get security updates. Use a supported version of PHP, such as PHP 8.

Comment: You don't have xdebug enabled. Please configure it accordingly: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html